# set a session value to jsp hidden form value

Tags: forms, jsp, session, jstl

I'm retrieving and set into a session a value(data).

```
session.setAttribute("data", result.getBody().getData());
```

How can i set the value of the session into the form value? The path data accepts String values.

```
<td><form:input type="hidden" path="data" value="?"/></td>
```

Is this possible? Should i use a JSTL function to succeed this?

Answer (score 1):

Try something as follows (with EL):

```
<form:input type="hidden" value="${sessionScope.data}"/>
```